# eclipse remove unselected breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Is there a way to remove only the unselected breakpoints in eclipse?
The reason is so that i could easily remove those breakpoints that i'm not currently involved in.

I don't want to break my flow of concentration with choosing things that aren't near the things i'm concentrating on.

I could just then disable all and select only those that i'm interested in debugging while not forgetting which debugs mattered in this most current problem.

OR...

Is there an invert selection of breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'Breakpoint'-View you could start with ALT+SHIFT+Q,B (or using Window->Show View->Breakpoints). 
You can select, activate and even delete All/selected breakpoints.

If you are working at a specific topic, try using MyIyn, as you can even focus your breakpoints on the task you are working at.

Comment: i already know this, what i want is after i have selected what i need i want those that i haven't selected to be removed, or at least i could invert my selection..so i can then prese the remove selected menu item

Comment: imo there is no option for invert the selection/delete the "not selected" breakpoints.

the only solution imo is using MyIyn